# Can i use / move an MVC Controller as Azure Function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, azure-functions

When i have an MVC Controller the return type is an `IActionResult`

```
public IActionResult Index(){
        return View();
    }
```

For a simple Azure Function i could return `Task<IActionResult>`. So can i move an MVC Controller to an Azure Function?

I think it's not possible to return a `ViewResult` from an Azure Function is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

From an azure function you can return anything, but the issue is that your `View` is embedded in the MVC engine, so in pure azure function it will not work as you might expect